# Run exe is missing from Windows 10

Tags: windows-10-preview, run-dialog

I am missing the run command from my computer. I do not mean from the menu. I mean the actual `exe` seems to be gone. I can type `run` in the search field on the Start Menu and it shows the Desktop App icon but if I click it nothing happens. If I press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> nothing happens.

I never get an error or anything it just doesn't launch the run prompt dialog box. I am on Windows 10 Pro Insider Preview build number 14295.1000. I run Avast Anti-Virus.

My only theory at this point is that Avast falsely identified the `exe` as a virus and deleted it. Can anyone tell me how to go about repairing this issue, please? I tried to Google it but all I get are countless articles on how to add Run to the Start Menu.

Comment: There is no `run.exe`

Comment: Sounds like you should reset your installation, based on the description, your installation is hosed.  As correctly pointed out, there is no "run.exe" it has never existed, I suspect you just have a incompatible program installed.

Comment: Run is an extension of Explorer.exe, task manager will show this.

Comment: in general, if you suspect some of your system files are corrupted (or deleted by antivirus), running **dism restorehealth** followed by **sfc scannow** should fix it in Win8.1+. (you may need your install media or a working Internet connection to Windows Update to download the missing/corrupted files, though) -> see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/947821

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since there is a third party security application on your system.
we could boot into clean boot then press Windows+R again to have a test in case it is blocked by third party security application .
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929135

if the issue persists, your current system files might be corrupted.
Please try to scan and restore your current system component using "DISM"command.
dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth

If above method doesn’t work. I suggest to execute a system restore, this way can restore your system to a previous healthy state which can resolve present problems.

Best regards

Comment: Avast was causing this issue.